# odi column lineage query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, etl, oracle-data-integrator

I have no odi experience and i have inherited an oracle data warehouse fed by odi implementations. I need to validate the source to target flows for several fields.My first attempt is to try to create a lineage using oracle's metadata. I am using the following query (from [this blog-post](https://www.clearpeaks.com/oracle-data-integrator-11g-ii-data-lineage/)):

```
select distinct 

  -- FOLDERS : more levels can be included, if needed (update the join conditions accordingly)
  PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME PROJECT,
  FOLDER_LVL1.FOLDER_NAME LVL1_FOLDER,
  FOLDER_LVL2.FOLDER_NAME LVL2_FOLDER,
  FOLDER_LVL3.FOLDER_NAME LVL3_FOLDER,
  --INTERFACE
  I.POP_NAME INTERFACE,
  case when I.WSTAGE = 'E' then 'N' else 'Y' end TEMPORARY_INTERFACE, -- WSTAGE can be: E - Existing target or N,W - Temporary target

  -- SOURCE
  SRC_TMP.POP_NAME SOURCE_TMP, -- temporary interface as the source
  SRC_MOD.MOD_NAME SOURCE_MODEL,
  SRC_TAB.TABLE_NAME SOURCE_TABLE,
  SRC_TAB.RES_NAME SOURCE_TABLE_RES_NAME,
  SRC_COL.COL_NAME SOURCE_COLUMN,
  SRC_COL.SOURCE_DT || '(' || SRC_COL.LONGC || case when SRC_COL.SCALEC is not null then ',' || SRC_COL.SCALEC else '' end || ')' SOURCE_COLUMN_DATATYPE,

  -- TARGET
  TGT_MOD.MOD_NAME TARGET_MODEL,   
  case when I.WSTAGE = 'E' then TGT_TAB.TABLE_NAME || '(' || TGT_TAB.RES_NAME || ')' else I.TABLE_NAME end TARGET_TABLE,
  case when I.WSTAGE = 'E' then TGT_TAB.RES_NAME else null end TARGET_TABLE_RES_NAME,
  case when I.WSTAGE = 'E' then TGT_COL.COL_NAME else TGT_POP_COL.COL_NAME end TARGET_COLUMN,
  case
    when I.WSTAGE = 'E' then TGT_COL.SOURCE_DT || '(' || TGT_COL.LONGC || case when TGT_COL.SCALEC is not null then ',' || TGT_COL.SCALEC else '' end || ')'
    else TGT_POP_COL.SOURCE_DT || '(' || TGT_POP_COL.LONGC || case when TGT_POP_COL.SCALEC is not null then ',' || TGT_POP_COL.SCALEC else '' end || ')'
  end TARGET_COLUMN_DATATYPE,
  case when TGT_POP_COL.IND_KEY_UPD = 1 then 'Y' else null end PRIMARY_KEY,

  -- MAPPING VALUE
  MAP_VAL_FULL.STRING_ELT FULL_ELT_STRING

from SNP_PROJECT PROJECT
  left outer join SNP_FOLDER FOLDER_LVL1 on FOLDER_LVL1.I_PROJECT = PROJECT.I_PROJECT -- FIRST FOLDER LEVEL
  left outer join SNP_FOLDER FOLDER_LVL2 on FOLDER_LVL2.PAR_I_FOLDER = FOLDER_LVL1.I_FOLDER -- SECOND FOLDER LEVEL
  left outer join SNP_FOLDER FOLDER_LVL3 on FOLDER_LVL3.PAR_I_FOLDER = FOLDER_LVL2.I_FOLDER
  left outer join SNP_POP I on I.I_FOLDER = FOLDER_LVL2.I_FOLDER -- INTERFACES IN THE 2nd LEVEL FOLDER

  left outer join SNP_POP_COL TGT_POP_COL on TGT_POP_COL.I_POP = I.I_POP -- TARGET COLUMNS OF THE INTERFACES
  left outer join SNP_COL TGT_COL on TGT_COL.I_COL = TGT_POP_COL.I_COL -- TARGET COLUMNS DETAILS
  left outer join SNP_TABLE TGT_TAB on TGT_TAB.I_TABLE = TGT_COL.I_TABLE -- TARGET TABLE DETAILS
  left outer join SNP_MODEL TGT_MOD on TGT_MOD.I_MOD = TGT_TAB.I_MOD -- TARGET TABLE MODEL

  left outer join SNP_POP_MAPPING MAP on MAP.I_POP_COL = TGT_POP_COL.I_POP_COL 
  left outer join SNP_TXT_CROSSR MAP_VAL on MAP_VAL.I_TXT = MAP.I_TXT_MAP and MAP_VAL.OBJECT_TYPE in ('C', 'P', 'V') 
  left outer join SNP_COL SRC_COL on SRC_COL.I_COL = MAP_VAL.I_COL -- SOURCE COLUMN DETAILS
  left outer join SNP_TABLE SRC_TAB on SRC_TAB.I_TABLE = SRC_COL.I_TABLE -- SOURCE TABLE DETAILS
  left outer join SNP_MODEL SRC_MOD on SRC_MOD.I_MOD = SRC_TAB.I_MOD -- SOURCE TABLE MODEL
  left outer join SNP_DATA_SET DATA_SET on I.I_POP = DATA_SET.I_POP 
  left outer join SNP_SOURCE_TAB SOURCE_TAB on DATA_SET.I_DATA_SET = SOURCE_TAB.I_DATA_SET
  left outer join SNP_POP SRC_TMP on SOURCE_TAB.I_POP_SUB = SRC_TMP.I_POP -- TEMPORARY SOURCE

  left outer join (
    select I_TXT, STRING_POS, STRING_ELT, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by I_TXT order by length(STRING_ELT) desc) POS 
    from SNP_TXT_CROSSR 
   ) MAP_VAL_FULL on MAP_VAL_FULL.I_TXT = MAP_VAL.I_TXT and MAP_VAL_FULL.POS = 1

where 1=1 -- FILTERS
   and PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME = 'DIM' -- by Project name
  and FOLDER_LVL1.FOLDER_NAME like 'FACT%' -- by 1st Level Folder name
  and FOLDER_LVL2.FOLDER_NAME like 'PREP%' -- by 2nd Level Folder name
  and FOLDER_LVL3.FOLDER_NAME like '%BUND%'
  --and I.POP_NAME not like 'Copy%' -- by Interface name
  and SRC_TAB.TABLE_NAME like '%WC_LHA%PS%' -- by Source Table name
  and SRC_COL.COL_NAME like '%EMPLOYEE_ID' -- by Source Column name
 and TGT_TAB.TABLE_NAME like '%PRODUCT%' -- by Target Table name
  and TGT_COL.COL_NAME like '%ORDER%'  -- by Target Column name
  and MAP_VAL_FULL.STRING_ELT like '%COALESCE(%' -- by Mapping Value

order by 
  PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME
  , FOLDER_LVL1.FOLDER_NAME
  , FOLDER_LVL2.FOLDER_NAME 
  , I.POP_NAME 
  , SRC_COL.COL_NAME
  , case when I.WSTAGE = 'E' then TGT_COL.COL_NAME else TGT_POP_COL.COL_NAME end
;
```

In ODI my project's structure is as follows:

Project Title --> Folder lvl 1 --> Folder lvl 2--> Folder lvl 3-->
and there we have the packages and mappings.

Using the query above returns null. I believe this happens because SNP_POP is empty thus there are no interfaces to query and i am clearly on the wrong path. Is there any other query to help me get a high level data lineage for each field before diving in ODI and search in the actual implementation. Is there any way to find in which project and which package a column is used as target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODI 12c brought a big change in the core element of ODI, replacing interfaces with mappings. The query you tried to use is for ODI 11g and is looking for interfaces, stored in SNP_POP. You need to look at SNP_MAPPING, SNP_MAP_CP and SNP_MAP_COMP and SNP_MAP_REF instead.

However it is not as easy as it used to be to get the full lineage of a mapping because there can be multiple components the source and the target. Also the multiple targets makes it more difficult.

Here is an example to get all the target attributes from Michael Rainey : https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2016/02/di-tips-odi12c-repo-query-mapping-target-table/

```
select
    m.name mapping_name,
    mr.qualified_name,
    mc.name datastore_alias,
    t.table_name target_table,
    mdl.cod_mod model_code
from snp_mapping m inner join snp_map_comp mc on m.i_mapping = mc.i_owner_mapping
    inner join snp_map_cp cp on mc.i_map_comp = cp.i_owner_map_comp
    inner join snp_map_ref mr on mc.i_map_ref = mr.i_map_ref
    inner join snp_table t on mr.i_ref_id = t.i_table
    inner join snp_model mdl on t.i_mod = mdl.i_mod
where cp.direction = 'O' and --output connection point
    cp.i_map_cp not in
        (select i_start_map_cp from snp_map_conn) --not a starting connection point;
```